# Force content to fit full width before sidebar collapsed Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

View having a sidebar and am appending div on load using Jquery .The problem is the sidebar space remains if the sidebar button is not pressed.'
[image: Before the button pressed]

When the sidebar collapsed the div is filled in the space like this 
[image: After Button pressed]

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-filter" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Filter
      </button>
        <div class="innerf-pages section content "  >
            <div class="fh-container mx-auto">
                <div class="row my-lg-5 mb-5" id="my">
                    <!-- grid left -->
                    <div class="side-bar col-lg-3 collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        //Some Divs
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-9 mt-lg-0 mt-5 right-product-grid ">
                    <!-- card group  -->
                    <div class="card-group" id="card-group">

                         //**After button click the following div get appended**

                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
                                <div class="card product-men p-3">
                                    <div class="men-thumb-item">
                                       // some content
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                      </div>
                </div>


          **//end**

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the space to the left of the first card in the first screenshot? Should that card align with the blue "Filter" button on the left?

Comment: space to the right

Comment: try adding the class `justify-content-end` to your `.row` (div with id `my`)

Comment: it creates the the space at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it stay opened ":onhover" CSS event. Or you can use Jquery to check the same event is still happening.

Comment: can u explain little more?

Comment: You can use the hover event of the sidebar class to make the sidebar stay open while you are on it and close it when you leave it.